# WHAT is the shortcut of sublime text 3 for formating

Tags: format, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Hey Guys Can You TEll me a shortcut of sublime text 3 for format code but i don't won't to know plugins bcoz i'm begginer

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+P or Command+Shift+P on MacOS to open the tools pallet, type reindent, and pick Indentation: Reindent Lines. It should reindent all the file you are in, just remember to save before running the command, or it may not appear.